# Getting CDATA from XML using SMXMLDocument in iOS

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, cdata

I'm coding an iOS app and I need to parse some values from an XML file.
I'm parsing the XML using [SMXMLDocument](https://github.com/nfarina/xmldocument) and everything works smooth but some tags are returning null value. I noted that those tags are CDATA and after some research I found some methods to workaround this thing. The problem is all those methods refer to NSXMLParser and I can't understand how to do this using SMXMLDocument.
The code in my app is very similar (you could say identical) to the code at [this page](https://github.com/nfarina/xmldocument/blob/master/XMLDocumentSamples/AppDelegate.m).
Can you please help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `SMXMLDocument` does not conform to all of the NSXMLParser delegate functions when it parses your document.  You are going to have to manually modify `SMXMLDocument.m` and add the function:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
 {  

}
```

Inside that function should look very similar to the foundcharacters function, you just need to take the `NSData` that you get and convert it into a string.  Beware of encoding though, CData data is not always UTF8.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Unfortunately I couldn't seem to make it work using the SMXMLDocument so I simply used NSXMLParser and its methods.